# How strong are google's Application-specific passwords?

Tags: passwords, authentication, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Account: implications of using application-specific passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/google-account-implications-of-using-application-specific-passwords)

In 2-step verification of google accounts, we need to use the Application-specific passwords generated by Google for use of applications. 
Even though it is generated by Google it is composed of only small case characters like 
"`bmkf wjug rtul opef`"

How much safe if this password against known attacks?