# How long it will take to crack a RAR password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, brute-force, password-cracking

I wonder how long it will take to crack 16 character alphanumeric WinRAR password for a mini supercomputer. As far as I know graphic cards are preferred over CPUs to crack passwords nowadays. If we consider that the cracker (law enforcment) uses the latest technologies to crack the RAR password and has pretty much computing power how long it will take for him to crack the password?

Comment: If you mean 16 completely random alphanumeric characters, then it's infeasible even for state level adversaries. I'd estimate a ~112 bit security level, which should be good for several decades.

Comment: With a policy which mandates a password change every one week , now top this with what @CodesInChaos said its just become very impractical.

Comment: @Saladin A password-change policy wouldn't actually have any effect at all, since we're talking about a password on a file.  At any given point in time the file has a password that can't be invalidated if the file is copied, so the frequency with which it is changed is immaterial to the feasibility of a brute-force attack.

Comment: @Xander okay i was thinking somewhere along the lines of a static file kept on a secure server (without any copies rights) which the attacker is trying to bruteforce. If it has been already copied (e.g in usb) then you are right, it wouldn't have any effect. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @CodesInChaos 16 characters chosen among all the alphanumeric characters in ASCII gives you around 95 bits of entropy not 112.

Comment: @kasperd 95 bits of entropy + 17 bits of iterated hashing = 112 bits of security. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A completely random alphanumeric password of length 16 has an entropy of 95 bits (16*log<sub>2</sub>(2*26+10)). I forgot the exact value, but I think rar uses around 100k iterations for its KDF, increasing the security level by about 17 bits, resulting in an effective security level of 112 bits.

With standard GPUs breaking this would cost around $10<sup>19</sup>. Custom hardware shaves off a factor 100 or so, still giving you a cost of $10<sup>17</sup>. Even if Moore's law continues, it'll take several decades until this is remotely feasible.

Related question: [How expensive is it to guess a 15 character password, and should I be worried?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12114/how-expensive-is-it-to-guess-a-15-character-password-and-should-i-be-worried/12121#12121)

Comment: I just would like to mention that RAR uses 262144 SHA-1 iterations in its KDF.

Comment: For anyone wondering the significance of that number, it's just `0x40000`, or 2^18.